# In R, which() is returning integer(0) for the search of a word within a book

Tags: r

I'm sorry if this has been covered but I can't find a comparable question that's helpful here or anywhere else that isn't much too complicated for my beginner self. I just started learning R and am trying a practice problem that is literally identical to the one I was working on from the textbook, just with Jane Austen instead of Melville. Right now I'm trying to establish the beginning and end of the text so I can get rid of the metadata and be left with just the text. Here is my code:

```
# import the file
text.v <- scan("data/plainText/austen.txt", what="character", sep="\n")
# find the first and last sentences
start.v <- which(text.v == "CHAPTER 1. The family of Dashwood")
end.v <- which(text.v == "live twenty years longer.")
```

When I run it and then enter `start.v` or `end.v` into the console, I get `integer(0)`.

However, the comparable code with the Melville returns the proper values.

```
#load text file
text.v <- scan("data/plainText/melville.txt", what="character", sep="\n")
text.v #view whole book
text.v[1] #view first line of book, as separated by \n
#create "bookmarks" to show the beginning and end of text
start.v <- which(text.v == "CHAPTER 1. Loomings.")
end.v <- which(text.v == "orphan.")
```

Comment: You can check for any `leading/lagging` spaces and also `==` works on the entire string and not on substrings, one option is `grep("CHAPTER 1. Loomings.", text.v)`

Comment: Try just looking for `"CHAPTER 1."`, it may not be in capitals or it may be stylized differently. Is "The family of Dashwood" the name of the chapter of the start of the chapter text? This might throw things off

Comment: add `fixed = TRUE` to `grep` or `.` will be interpreted as a wildcard

Comment: The [janeauestenr](https://github.com/juliasilge/janeaustenr) package has them already neatly available, or see [gutenbergr](http://github.com/ropenscilabs/gutenbergr) for others. And generally `grep` is very helpful here when you don't know what the formatting might look like but do know the content.

Comment: What do you get when you view the result of the scan of austen.txt?  It's possible the line endings are different in that text and you aren't getting what you expect in text.v.